# UIBezierPath and line thickness

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

Let say I have this snippet to draw a line.

```
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + cellWidth * i + kLineThickness, y)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + cellWidth *i + kLineThickness, y + cellWidth * cells + kLineThickness)];
```

Where does the pixel of the line begin?  Does it divide the line thickness evenly on both side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101):

> The line width is the total width of the line, expressed in units of
>   the user space. The line straddles the path, with half of the total
>   width on either side.

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided will draw a vertical line as both coordinates have the same x coordinate.It will not be affecting the thickness at all. The pixel of the line starts from (x + cellWidth * i + kLineThickness, y).

You modify the width of the line by specifying it before drawing the line using the function:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGontextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x1,y1)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x2,y2)];
```

The above code will make a line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) using the width as lineWidth.

Also, you need the current context to draw into. Please go through the apple documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-SW1